# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose 3k}\le\frac{1}{3}(2^n+2) \text{such that } n>0$ and $k$ is the largest number for which $3k\le n$

Tags: inequality, summation, combinations

I tried it using induction

For $n=1,\displaystyle{1\choose 0}\le\dfrac{1}{3}(2^1+2)$

Let for $m\le n $ it is true i.e  $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{m\choose 3k}\le\dfrac{1}{3}(2^m+2)$

Now we need to prove for $m+1 \le n,\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{m+1\choose 3k}\le\dfrac{1}{3}(2^{m+1}+2)$

Now $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{m+1\choose 3k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{m\choose 3k}+\sum_{k=1}^n {m\choose {3k-1}}$

Now the in the RHS, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{m\choose 3k}+\sum_{k=1}^n {m\choose {3k-1}}\le \dfrac{1}{3}(2^m+2)+\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n {m\choose {3k-1}}}_{\text{Lets call this X}}=\dfrac{1}{3}(2^m+2)+X$
But how do I show $X \le \dfrac{1}{3}(2^m)$ in order to prove $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}{m\choose 3k}+\sum_{k=1}^n {m\choose {3k-1}} \le \dfrac{1}{3}(2^{m+1}+2)$

Comment: Can you take a look at your sum please, something went wrong. The upper bound should be $n$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Well as of now I don't see what went wrong. Atleast I can't find it.No No I corrected it. Please have a look.

Comment: Please [stop adding `dfrac` and `displaystyle` in title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189).

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No No I corrected it. Please have a look

Comment: Must you use this induction tool?

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner Can you suggest me something else please?

Comment: Title still absurd. The symbol $k$ might be used for two different purposes.

Comment: I agree with @Did that the title is not clear. See the answer for how to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not hard to notice that the left-hand side is equal to $\frac 13 \left((1+\zeta_3)^n + (1+\zeta_3^2)^n + (1+\zeta_3^3)^n\right)$, where $\zeta_3$ is the third root of unity. Now the inequality is equivalent to:

$$(1+\zeta_3)^n + (1+\zeta_3^2)^n \le 2$$

However now we have that $1+\zeta_3 = \zeta_6$ and $1+\zeta_3^2 = \zeta_6^5$ and we have that as the left-hand side is real:

$$ (1+\zeta_3)^n + (1+\zeta_3^2)^n = \left| (1+\zeta_3)^n + (1+\zeta_3^2)^n \right| = \left|\zeta_6^{5n} + \zeta_6^{n}\right| \le \left|\zeta_6^{5n}\right| + \left|\zeta_6^{n}\right| = \left|\zeta_6\right|^{5n} + \left|\zeta_6\right|^{n}=2$$

Hence the proof.

Comment: it is fantastic! Give me that brain!

Comment: Check that **“fact”**; say for $n=4, j=1$. It says $12\le 11$?

Comment: @Macavity Is it? I have not been solving this problem. Can you help me please!

Comment: @Macavity Yeah, you are right the "fact" is wrong, as I forgot that the binomial coefficient changes convexity at each $n$. It seems I was forced to bring out the "heavy artilery". I though I found an easier solution at the beginning, that's why I didn't want to post this one.

Comment: @Saradamani Check my solution. It's a bit more advanced, but I think you can understand.

Comment: @Stefan4024 OTOH I have found binomial coefficients to be concave ;)  The roots of unity approach works of course, +1

Comment: @Stefan4024 I fully understand your proof. It is crisp and a bit out of the box thinking. The answer shows the touch of a real genius. By the bye I appreciate people too much- I have a disrepute for that! Please do not consider it as a snobbish remark but an appreciation for the ingenuity of your work.

Comment: @Stefan4024  I could not sleep the night before yesterday. So I slept early last night. Now I am seeing your answer.Many Many thanks for the pain you have taken.